# Android Studio - Failed to resolve sync ML Kit sample

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

So im trying to run this [sample from ML kit](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit).
I just created the firebase project and added the google-services.json file.

Im getting this errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:16.1.2
```

Any idea why?

PS: Im really new to this so if there is any information i can add to give clues about what is happening just ask and i ll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mismatch of the version number. The gradle file is reverted. Please try again for the sample app, and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Sample app update was published before SDK was released. This should no longer be an issue now.